# How to use special characters in MySQL column names?

Tags: mysql, create-table

Here is my failing MySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
            id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            'item-name' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            'item-description' TEXT,
            'listing-id' VARCHAR(50),
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
        )
```

The error is:

> Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'item-name' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 'item-description' TEXT, 'listing-id'' at line 3

The documentation says to use quotes... What is wrong?

Comment: I would suggest just using underscores.  That is much more common practice. So use `item_name`, `item_description`, `listing_id`. To answer your question though, you need backticks not quotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `` ` `` instead of `'`:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
        id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `item-name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `item-description` TEXT,
        `listing-id` VARCHAR(50),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
```

Comment: what buttons I have to press on the mac to do this symbol?

Comment: @MatthewBazanet Oooh, not sure - is it not on the top left of the keyboard? Not sure as I only ever use PCs. If all else fails you could always copy and paste from here. But I guess that's not a good long-term solution. Other alternative (as others have suggested) is to use underscores instead of hyphens in your column names - then you won't need the backticks.

Comment: I have replace and the code works and I have discovered where is the backticks symbol in my italian mac book pro: alt+top left button

Comment: Is there anyway I can add backquotes(`) as a special character in the column name?

Comment: @Echo Yes - to do this, use a double backtick (``) instead of a single backtick (`) in the column name to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use quotes? You should use backticks. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `item-name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `item-description` TEXT,
    `listing-id` VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the back-quote (`) to quote column names, not the single-quote ('). Look above the tilde key (~).

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `item-name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `item-description` TEXT,
    `listing-id` VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use normal character in table definition. You can use underscore "_" instead "-".

When you'll query your db, you must always use quote. Impossible for me! :)

If you want follow this road, use the quote

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `item-name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `item-description` TEXT,
    `listing-id` VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is coming late. but this worked for me.

CREATE TABLE product (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
[item-name] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[item-description] TEXT,
[listing-id] VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: puting them in square brackets [] did the trick.