# python mysql syntax error - VALUES ('2' at line 1")

Tags: python, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am new in python . I try write skript for parsing to mysql. Part of my code :

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="me", passwd="passwd", db="Data")

with db:
  cursor = db.cursor()    
  with open("my.log","rw") as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
    result = parser(line)
    resultS = parserS(result[3])
    format = '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f %Y]'
    now = datetime.datetime.strptime(result[0], format)

    sql = ("INSERT INTO Data.table1 (time, level, id, error, file ,ip, request) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
    data = (now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f'), result[1], result[2], ' ' ,resultS[0],resultS[1],resultS[2])
    cursor.execute(sql, data)


f.close()
db.close()
```

When I try to run it give me that message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parsingApacheErrorFrom.py", line 81, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-error (time, log_level, pid, error_status, file ,client_ip, message) VALUES ('2' at line 1")
```

I try to find error in my sql syntax but it look fine for me. And I dont understood what mean :  VALUES ('2' at line 1") ??? In mysql table, first column is type datetime, all others columns are varchar (255).

Comment: What happens if you just use `now` instead of `now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f')`?

Comment: can you give it a try with `VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')` ?

Comment: can we see the complete query that it's trying to run? just wrap your execute() in a try/except and inside the except run `print(cursor._last_executed)`

Comment: maybe `;` in the end of sequence will help

Comment: well it write same error. I think that in datatime is not problem, I use this `now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f')` in my previous code and it work.

Comment: if I try VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') it write same error but on end is `'-error (time, log_level, pid, error_status, file ,client_ip, message) VALUES (''' at line 1")`

Comment: remarkable, I don't see any difference.

Comment: Where is the `-` in `-error` coming from? I think you have two different queries and you're looking at the wrong code. This one does not match what's in the error.

Comment: well my table real name is not table1 but it is apache-log-error . It can be problem for python ?

Comment: ok problem is in table name. When I rename it on tabletest, it works fine. How can I write sql query if I want table name  apache-log-error ? Or it is imposible in python ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951180/how-to-use-special-characters-in-column-names